# Subfolders in UP folder chucknorris/roundhouse

Tags: sql-server, deployment, roundhouse

I was wondering if it is possible to have subfolders in the UP folder of the chucknorris/roundhouse project. Instead of lumping together all scripts into the UP folder, my team would like to organize the new scripts by "release #" and have a different folder per release. Does this screw up the point of the up folder or is this feature built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have subfolders. See https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions#folder-locations

Also be sure that all files in the up folder are uniquely named, no matter what folder/subfolder they are in.

This means you cannot have `up/release1/0001_firstscript.sql` and `up/release2/0001_firstscript.sql`.

Comment: You can also have it search across all subdirectories at once using -searchallinsteadoftraverse - https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions#switches and is the option to search all folders at once instead of traverse and put everything in order that way instead of using the folders as a secondary order, but I don't think that is what you are looking for, so I added it as a comment instead.

Comment: when Roundhouse traverses the subfolders in the UP folder, does it do so alphabetically? So, would all of the scripts in the release1 folder be executed before all the scripts in the release2 folder, regardless of what the script files themselves are named?

Comment: Depends on how you pass the folder traverse option. By default I'm pretty sure it's by folder, then by name of file